# Calling methods from dlls

Tags: c++, dll

In my project we have set of existing dlls, which I will like to use as it is. But this will create cascaded calls across multiple dll. Below will be call flow:

1. First.dll will call Second.dll for getting information in already created memory block. (pointer of memory block will be handed to second dll to get output data.)
2. Second.dll will call Third.dll and will handover pointer of memory block (originally created by First.dll)

What are the problems my application face? Please tell me advanatges and disadvantages of this proposal.

Note: The First.dll and Second.dll will be newly developed.Third.dll is existing dll, which will be reused. Even in future, we might have scenario when Third.dll can be newly developed. I want to know that is there any problem application can face with cascaded calls among multiple dlls?

Comment: If they are existing dlls that you aren't changing wouldn't they already be working in this fashion?

Comment: What is the point of this question? Are you considering refactoring your project? Are you experiencing any problems?

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect the reused dll and newly developed dlls.

Answer (score 0):

**"If it works, don't fix it"** meaning if they work "as is" then it's fine. I gather these DLLs are existing ones? Thus already designed and **tested** to work together? If so, they will also work for you. Cheers.

However, if you are planning on building these on your own or have an alternate set of DLLs, then I'd suggest using a more simple architecture with no cascading DLLs. It's easier to debug and develop when there are fewer DLLs or DLL levels around. Though, don't bother doing yourself if you have a tested setup at hand.

Comment: Ah, you updated your question. DLLs will add a layer of complexity into your application. It will be harder to develop and debug. I wouldn't bother if those DLLs are not used anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

DLLs should only be used in this context when you want to separate shared functionality out for purposes of using them in different projects. If you only have one program that you need to access the functionality from, there's no reason to separate it out to a library.

In the case of cascaded calls, you'll face heavier overheads than calls from within your own application. This is because the assembly changes.

Here's a very rough representation of what a normal call looks like for a class member:

```
push 0                   ; a parameter
push 1                   ; another parameter
push eax                 ; pointer to the class instance
call Program.SomeMethod  ; direct call to the method
```

This is very fast. When you include DLLs, you have to perform the call through the IAT. This increases execution time. Again this is a gross simplification:

```
push 0
push 1
push eax
call <Program.IAT_1>
...
Program.IAT_1:
  jmp DLL1.SomeCall
...
DLL1.SomeCall:
  ; more code here
  call <DLL1.IAT_1>
...
DLL1.IAT_1:
  jmp DLL2.SomeOtherCall
...
DLL2.SomeOtherCall
  ; actual code here
  ret
```

Since you're calling across modules, it'll cause a significant overhead if you're calling this function frequently.

There's also a myriad of issues related to maintainance and deployment that make it even more prudent not to split things out when it's not neccessary.

In this case, the only reason you should split it out is if you plan to use some code in another application. Even in this case, you shouldn't need more than one DLL.

Comment: Just spotted your update. Keep in mind the performance issues, and only split out classes where you need to. If you're only using a class in one application, keep it in that application's code. Anything you're sharing should be placed in a single shared DLL, separated across major functionality if you're building a significant library. Anything more is probably overkill.